# How do I get onclick attribute to work with pop up plugin on wordpress site?

Tags: html, wordpress

Using the PopUp plugin by subsystic, they claim that adding the following on click attribute to my site will trigger the pop up form I've created when clicking a specific link.

onclick="ppsShowPopup(100); return false;"

This is what my code looks like:

```
<a href="http://www.it-erative.com" onclick="ppsShowPopup(100); return false;"><p class="text">REQUEST DEMO</p></a>
```

but the pop up doesn't show.

Comment: Your website's link would be helpful to view all the codes.

Comment: Make sure yout PopUp plugins js files are being loaded into the page you have your button

Comment: Are you getting any js error?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <a href onclick="ppsShowPopup(100); return false;"><p class="text">REQUEST DEMO</p></a>
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) There are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: Hi, I understand, but my English is not very well, sorry

Comment: Give it a try! We have lots of users with very little english. We are patient. :) Tell us what is different about your answer. What did you change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used the shortcode to intiate the popup: `[supsystic-show-popup id=101]` ([see documentation](http://supsystic.com/open-popup-on-click/))

But popup was not showing up when clicked on the button. The problem was that I was using the shortcode in the header template. **By default wordpress only processes the shortcode in post/page content**.

In order to enable the popup in your desired location use `do_shortcode()` function.

Example: To use shortcodes in the template files:

```
<?php do_shortcode('[short_code_string_here]'); ?>
```